# Robotframework and Eclipse does not find runtime environment for project

Tags: robotframework

I have Python, Eclipse and Robotframework (RED) installed on MacOS (Big Sur).

I have created a User Library with some Python functions and the config file for robot framework, "project.robot" where I defined the test cases. From the terminal I am able to run the test cases with

> python -m robot Tests/project.robot

But when I try to run the same configuration in Eclipse, it says:

```
There is no active runtime environment for project 'robotest'
```

Eclipse is configured and able to run Python Projects, but I did not find the part where I can make Eclipse recognized that robot framework is installed properly (because all is fine an running from command line).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try the version of eclipse with already preinstalled red plugin that can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/nokia/RED/releases/tag/0.9.5

- Switch to robot perspective: Window->Perspective->Open perspective ->
  Other...-> Robot
- Load load you project in the workspace
- Configure robot nature in order to generate red.xml -> right click on you project from project explorer -> Robot Framework -> Add Robot nature
- Check what you have in Window -> Preferences -> Robot Framewokr -> Installed Frameworks. If you don't have anything there try to add the path to you python installation by clicking the Add... button.

Also share the version and edition of eclipse, version of python, version of Robot Framework.

Comment: Finally i managed to install in the existing Eclipse the RED Plugin.